# i want to build a attandence system using face detection and face recognition in java

Tags: java, face-recognition

there are many resources out there to build face detection and face recognition in python . But for my college project i have to do this process using java . can anyone suggest me books or tutorial of face detection and face recognition in java . basically my idea is to build face recognition based attendance system using java . the program should identify the student in the class room multiple face detection such as using yolo in java(is it possible )?? then identify the student .then look at the database and update the attendance sheet . please help me out to build this project

Answer (score -1):

You can use `OpenCV` in order to detect and track a moving face into a video stream.
And for database tasks, `AWS Cloud` may suitable for you to matching faces and updating it.

For Reference -
[OpenCV FaceRecognition](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/08%20-%20Face%20Recognition%20and%20Tracking.html)

Comment: thanks for replying .detecting and tracking face using opencv might not me real time . i want detect multiple faces at a time . If there any way to use yolo or ssd model in java